# Monitor traffic of devices in your wireless network

Tags: wireless-router

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Monitor Network Traffic on WPA](https://superuser.com/questions/89875/monitor-network-traffic-on-wpa)

Is it possible to monitor/sniff wireless traffic of devices connected to your wireless network?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)

Comment: Actually I am looking at it. But it shows only my local interfaces.

Comment: @JSR: See Lucas' answer. It is possible, but you need a suitable WiFi adapter. I recall the wireshark website covers this subject.

Comment: I have Motorola SBG901. Does it have some inbuilt support for this.

Comment: @JSR - Check the Wireshark website.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to find. Can someone point me to correct link? Device in my case is iphone.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, you can do this:

get a WIFI antenna that is capable of putting itself in monitoring mode and then use wireshark/tshark to analyze and capture data.